# setInterval() triggers another interval everytime page is visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, fullpage.js

Hi guys I'm using fullpage.js and I'm trying to make an autoslider on my homepage using setInterval(). The problem is that everytime I go to another page on my site and return to home the setInterval triggers another interval and the slider goes fast and crazy.

I'm using clearInterval() everytime the homepage is visited but it doesn't seems to work, any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

```
window.laytheme.on("newpageshown", function(layoutObj, type, obj){
    var myInter
    var autoScroll = function() {
    jQuery.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown()
    }

    if(obj.id === 11){
    clearInterval(myInter)
    myInter = setInterval(autoScroll, 3500)
    }

    })
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, could you provide more information? If you just need to run code with a delay, you can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, and it will execute once.

Comment: @JoseLM Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: Hi Anton, i have a homepage that has a fullscreen slider with 3 sections(slides), I need the slider to loop each one every 3500ms. With setInterval the first time i visit my homepage everything works perfect, the problem is when i visit another page on my site and return to the home. this seems to trigger another interval. I've tried using setTimeout and a recursive function but the problem still exist.

Comment: Problem was that i was not declaring my variables as global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change your code into setTimeout like below:

```
//ensure interval variable are accessible
var myInterval = null;
var autoScroll = function() {
    jQuery.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown()
};

window.laytheme.on("newpageshown", function(layoutObj, type, obj){
    if(obj.id === 11){
        if(myInterval != null){
            clearTimeout(myInterval);
        }
        myInterval = setTimeout(autoScroll, 3500);
    }
});
```